# Number of partitions when creating a Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The question has been asked in other thread, but it seems my problem doesn't fit in any of them.

I'm using Spark 2.4.4 in local mode, I set the master to `local[16]` to use 16 cores. I also see in the web UI 16 cores have been allocated.

I create a dataframe importing a csv file of about 8MB like this:

```
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("Datasets/globalpowerplantdatabasev120/*.csv")
```

finally I print the number of partitions the dataframe is made of:

```
df.rdd.partitions.size

res5: Int = 2
```

Answer is 2.

Why? As far as I read around, the number of partitions depends on the number of executors that is by default set equal the numer of cores(16).

I tried to set the number of esecutors using `spark.default.Parallelism = 4` and/or `spark.executor.instances = 4` and started a new spark object but nothing changed in the number of partitions.

Any suggestion?

Comment: 8MB is quite low.

Answer (score 1):

When you read a file using Spark the number of partitions is calculated as the maximum between defaultMinPartitions and the number of splits computed based on hadoop input split size divided by the block size. Since your file is small so the number of partitions you are getting is 2 which is the maximum of the two.

The default defaultMinPartitions is calculated as

```
def defaultMinPartitions: Int = math.min(defaultParallelism, 2)
```

Please check https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9f983df275c138626af35fd263a7abedf69297f/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2329

Comment: The defaultMinPartitions, according to the formula can either be 1 or 2. But this is a **minimum** number of partitions. Not the number of partitions itself.
The question stays, How is set the number of partitions?

Comment: Number of partitions is the max(defaultMinPartitions, number of splits computed based on hadoop input split size divided by the block size);

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Is this valid also for a normal filesystem? where do I find these parameters?

Comment: Spark uses Hadoop InputFilFormat under the hood, it will be reading partitions by input block. So you need to read Hadoop block size arrival logic.